# How to avoid duplicating property definitions when creating subclasses in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, init

In the following code, I believe I'm forced to type a redundancy whereby the init() functions for class Beverage and its subclass Beer both specify the properties *name* and *form*. But this seems counterintuitive, as my belief was that the benefit of using subclasses was the inheritance of class properties, so isn't retyping the superclass properties for each subclass self-defeating? (no pun intended). Further, it seems a bit absurd to require `super.init(form: form, name: name, etc: etc)` ad infinitum. Am I missing something?

```
class Beverage {
    var name: String
    var form: String
    
    init(name: String = "unknown",
         form: String = "liquid") {
        self.name = name
        self.form = form
    }
}

class Beer: Beverage {
    var alcohol: Double?
    
    init(name: String = "unknown",
         form: String = "liquid",
         alcohol: Double?) {
        self.alcohol = alcohol
        super.init(name: name, form: form)
    }
}
        
let myBev = Beer(name: "Heineken", alcohol: 0.05)

if let alcohol = myBev.alcohol {
    print("I'm drinking a glass of \(myBev.name), which is a \(myBev.form) and has \(alcohol)% alcohol.")
} else {
    print("I'm drinking a glass of \(myBev.name), which is a \(myBev.form).")
}

// prints "I'm drinking a glass of Heineken, which is a liquid and has 0.05% alcohol."
```

I tried removing what I perceive to be redundant code but it no longer works; am I stuck with redundancy?

Comment: There's no redundancy. The properties are only in their one respective class. It's the parameters of the `init` that needs all properties. A `Beer` instance is a `Beverage` so `Beer` has 3 properties (one on its own and two inherited). To create a `Beer` instance you need to provide values for all 3 properties (or rely on the default values). If the `Beer` init didn't have parameters for `name` and `form`, how would you pass values for those properties when creating a `Beer` instance?

Comment: Can beer be anything but liquid in its form? If not then you could skip that parameter in the Beer initializer. One very simplified example where you can take advantage of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules you have to call `super` to initialize properties without default value declared in the base class.

But you can eliminate a bit redundancy by omitting parameters with fixed values for example in the `Beer` class it's clear that the form is `liquid`

```
class Beer: Beverage {
    var alcohol: Double
    
    init(name: String, alcohol: Double) {
        self.alcohol = alcohol
        super.init(name: name, form: "liquid")
    }
}
```

---

Another way is to add a convenience initializer for `liquid` beverages - which calls the designated initializer - in the base class

```
class Beverage {
    var name : String
    var form : String
    
    init(name: String, form: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.form = form
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init(name: name, form: "liquid")
    }
}
```

Then the code in `Beer` can be reduced to

```
class Beer: Beverage {
    var alcohol: Double
    
    convenience init(name: String, alcohol: Double) {
        self.init(name: name)
        self.alcohol = alcohol
    }
}
```

Note that the `convenience` initializers call `self` rather than `super`.

And I would declare `alcohol` non-optional.